# Is it possible to redirect your Laravel blade at a particular time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-controller

Please am trying to redirect a page in Laravel7 once a time is clocked e.g once the time is 04:05 the page should redirect.

I tried this below but it didn't work.

```
 public function countdown(){

        $currentdate = date("d-m-Y h:i:s");

        $futuredate = "02-05-2020 18:4:25";

        if($currentdate == $futuredate){
            return redirect()->route('welcome');
        }

    }
```

Can anyone help on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this on the client side, this can't be done on the server side.

You can use `setInterval` to execute a piece of code that will check if the time is 04:05 and then redirect the page using `window.location.href = "/yourroute";`

Something like this:

```js
setInterval(function () {
  var date = new Date();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var minute = date.getMinutes();

  if (hour === 4 && minute === 5) {
    location.href = "/welcome"
  }
}, 60000);
```

60000 is 1 minute in millieseconds.

Comment: please can you show me an example of how to do that. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It worked, am so grateful. I just reduced the 60000 to 12000 to make it redirect faster.